# Javascript - Issue with capturing value from API

Tags: javascript

I'm learning web development and I'm trying to learn the basics. I have made my own project to find the current ETH price.

My JS code is below:

https://pastebin.com/6ecrTZCu

```js
const button1 = document.querySelector('#eth');
const list = document.querySelector('#price');


const addPrice = async() => {
  const pricee = await checkPrice();
  console.log(pricee)
  const newLI = document.createElement('LI');
  newLI.append(pricee);
  list.append(newLI)
}



const checkPrice = async() => {
  axios.get('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/eth-aud')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.ticker.price)
      return res.data.ticker.price


    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Sorry, error!')
      return 'Sorry, error!'
    })
}

button1.addEventListener('click', addPrice)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bZS47S7sPOxkjU/4Bt0zrhEtWx0y0CRkhEp8IckzK+ltifIIE9EMIMTuT/mEzoIMewUINruDBIR/jJnbguonqQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="eth">Get ETH Price</button>

<br/><br/><br/>

<div id="price"></div>
```

Can anyone explain why it is not capturing 'res.data.ticker.price' in line 6? This is really frustrating me!

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: What do you mean by "capturing"? The code logs `undefined` (the return of `addPrice`) and then `3833.28404958` by `console.log(pricee)`

Comment: When it executes const pricee = await checkPrice(), I want that to return '3833.28404958' in the html if that makes sense. Instead, it will just append 'undefined', when I want it to return the 3833. The 'newLI.append(pricee)' should append the '3833' rather than 'undefined'.

Comment: It might be because `addEventListener` doesn’t understand async functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a promise from the checkPrice() method. Currently, You are returning nothing(void).

```
const checkPrice = async() => {
  return axios.get('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/eth-aud')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.ticker.price)
      return res.data.ticker.price


    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Sorry, error!')
      return 'Sorry, error!'
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason undefined is shown is because the checkPrice function returns immediately.
For this to function, checkPrice must return a Promise which can be awaited by the const pricee = await checkPrice(). Otherwise it returns immediately a undefined value.
Please check the corrected code.

```js
const button1 = document.querySelector('#eth');
const list = document.querySelector('#price');


const addPrice = async() => {
  const pricee = await checkPrice();
  console.log(pricee)
  const newLI = document.createElement('LI');
  newLI.append(pricee);
  list.append(newLI)
}



const checkPrice = async() => {
  return await axios.get('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/eth-aud')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.ticker.price)
      return Promise.resolve(res.data.ticker.price);


    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Sorry, error!')
      return 'Sorry, error!'
    })
}

button1.addEventListener('click', addPrice)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bZS47S7sPOxkjU/4Bt0zrhEtWx0y0CRkhEp8IckzK+ltifIIE9EMIMTuT/mEzoIMewUINruDBIR/jJnbguonqQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="eth">Get ETH Price</button>

<br/><br/><br/>

<div id="price"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the first console.log is that console.log is not async function for this reason this execute before the async function. I resolve your problem only asyn await

```js
const button1 = document.querySelector('#eth');
const list = document.querySelector('#price');


const addPrice = async() => {
  const pricee = await checkPrice();
  const newLI = document.createElement('LI');
  newLI.append(pricee);
  list.append(newLI)
}



const checkPrice = async() => {
  const result = await axios.get('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/eth-aud')
  return result.data.ticker.price
}

button1.addEventListener('click', addPrice)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bZS47S7sPOxkjU/4Bt0zrhEtWx0y0CRkhEp8IckzK+ltifIIE9EMIMTuT/mEzoIMewUINruDBIR/jJnbguonqQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="eth">Get ETH Price</button>

<br/><br/><br/>

<div id="price"></div>
```